# Passing custom props in react-hybrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an react app under angular app using ui-router(both angular and react). Under angular app, there is a nested view, for left and right panel. So when you click item on left panel, it show detail on right panel.

Current I am using react-hybrid and would like to make right panel(child) connect to left panel(parent). For example, click remove button on right panel will remove item in left panel. My idea is to pass a callback function as props to right panel like [UIView Pass Props & Propogate Changes To Children](https://github.com/ui-router/react/issues/26)

However, it does not pass custom props but only state props in react-hybrid. Here is my code.

In routes, I have

```
.state('reactapp', {
  url: '/reactapps',
  component: reactapp
})
.state('reactapp.deatil', {
  url: '/detail',
  component: deatil
})
```

reactApp.js

```
render() {
   const leftPanel = <List list={this.list}/>;
   const rightPanel = (
      <UIView render={(Component, props) => <Component {...props} callback={someCallback} />} />
   );
   return <Layout leftPanelComponent={leftPanel} rightPanelComponent={rightPanel} />;
}
```

By doing so, `reactapp` component will render  and show the detail component in it. But any idea how to pass custom props in react-hybrid or other workaround?